# Django-Chosen seems to be ignoring the widgets despite correct static_url

Tags: django, jquery-chosen

I can get my ManyToManyField into a chosen widget directly by using the chosen jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}projectx/projectx_chosen.js"></script>
```

**projectx_chosen.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_sales_item').chosen();
});
```

This clearly indicates that my static_url is setup correctly.

But trying to achieve the same thing with django-chosen has no effect whatsoever.

```
class DealType(models.Model):   
    sales_item          = models.ManyToManyField(SalesItem)


class DealTypeForm(ModelForm):   

    class Meta:
        model = DealType

        widgets = {
                    'sales_item': ChosenSelectMultiple(),
                   }
```

I have chosen.jquery.min.js under `{{STATIC_URL}}js/chosen.jquery.min.js`
and chosen.css under `{{STATIC_URL}}css/chosen.css`

Any idea why this is not working please?

**Update**

```
[21/Aug/2012 11:16:13] "GET /static/css/chosen.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[21/Aug/2012 11:16:16] "GET /static/js/chosen.jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

So now both are in the the path that the extension expects according to my investigation into the source code. And they are loaded.

Yet it simply doesn't work.

Using the chosen.js directly works like a charm, so I know how I would normally use it, but django-chosen, doesn't seem matured yet.

Comment: Can you check if the `js` and `css` is actually loading?

Comment: I have the files in the right place, do I also have to include them in the base.html?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that

Comment: @zsquare, thanks. Please see my updated question, but still no luck.

Comment: sure have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/GRTTm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by linking to the chosen.jquery.ready.js file. So I have:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/chosen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chosen.jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/chosen.jquery_ready.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks alan. I went to use the chosen.js directly without the django-chosen. So I tick this as an answer, without any verification. ;)